# permanently display hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
    <div id="div3"><img src="" width="20px" /></div>
    <div id="div4">
    ... -> menu
    </div>
```

which by using the following:

```
    div3{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    }


    #div4{
    display: none;
    float:right;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: -70px;
    }

    #div3:hover + #div4 {
    display: block;
    }
```

I make the div4 show, after hovering #div3 (which is an image) . However I want div4 appears and remains after uncovering the #div3. I tried couple of codes in jquery but they do not work.

can you help?

Comment: I don't really understand will z-index come in useful?

Comment: You can't do this with CSS, use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* (effectively) do this in pure CSS, such that it works in modern browsers. The trick is to use a very large value for a transition-delay when the hover exits. Like this:

```
#div3:hover + #div4 { opacity:1; height:20px;transition-delay:0s; }
#div4 { opacity:0; height:0; transition-delay:360000s; }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/7Fw3A/1/

Comment: It works now. Loved the idea of "delay in transition." Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As PHPGlue said, you can't do that with just CSS.

You can do something like this using jquery, adjust the code based on your needs:

**HTML**

```
<div id="one">Hover me!</div>
<div id="two">HELLOO!</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#one").on("hover", function(){
   $("#two").show(); 
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R37NA/)**

Comment: @PHPGlue I used the following code:

       <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#div3").on("hover", function(){
   $("#div4").show(); 
});

</script>

but it doesn't work. That is my problem with using jQuery since It doesn't seem like catching the selector Ids or class names.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that #div4 is always displayed while it is hovered over. Change your last CSS selector to something like:

```
#div3:hover + #div4, #div4:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

It will still go away when you move the mouse away from both div3 and div4, but that is often what you want to happen. If not, it's probably best to use a jQuery solution (I'm sure others will post one).

You could possibly add another transparent div that covered the full height and width of the page, give it a high z-index, and make sure that both it and div4 are displayed when that div is hovered over (as it will always be), but that sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, however the overarching goal is to have the "#div4" stays permanently. let me play with the z-index since it would be a good idea to use in this case!

Answer (score 0):

As PHPglue said, you need Javascript to do this. (this is only one example. feel free to use whatever JS you want)

```
$('#div3').hover(function() {
    $('#div4').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to make `#div4` to appear once you've hovered over `#div3`, so do the following.

```
$('#div3').on('mouseover', function () {
  $('#div4').addClass('visible');
  $(this).off('mouseover');
});
```

This will add the class `visible` to `#div4` when you mouseover `#div3` for the first time. If you add a css selector `.visible { visibility: visible; }` then this will adjust `#div4`s css.